# inner join returning only 1 row using like clause instead of two

Tags: mysql

I have the below sql, which if i take out the inner join to the table and hard code the values, i get 2 records. But when i use the inner join statement, i just get 1 record. I am aware that with MYSQL, the like clause, is not case sensitive. Here is the sql below. I dont know why it is only returning  row.

```
SELECT 
      a.project_code as projectCode, 
      a.project_name as projectName, 
      a.project_creation_date as projectCreationDate, 
      a.project_end_date as projectEndDate, 
      a.project_status as projectStatus      
from projects a 
inner join tmp_rec_naren8 b 
    on a.project_name like concat("%",b.expertise_desc,"%") 
    OR a.project_description like concat("%",b.expertise_desc,"%") ;
```

If I change the above to:

```
select *
from projects
where project_name like '%java%'
OR project_description like '%java%';
```

I get 2 rows and not 1.

Table `tmp_rec_naren8` has just one column `expertise_desc` and contains this data:

```
expertise_desc
--------------
XML
Python
DWH
Java
```

Table `projects` has many columns :.. But these below are the relevant ones

```
    project_code sr_user_name project_name project_descriiption ..
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    1             naren5      POS          C++, XML,Java
    2             naren7      INV          Networking
    3             naren9      CCV          Java, Unix
```

The first query returns 1 row:

```
    project_code sr_user_name project_name project_descriiption ..
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
     1            naren5       POS         C++,XML,Java
```

The second query returns 2 rows

```
    project_code sr_user_name project_name project_descriiption ..
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    1             naren5      POS          C++, XML,Java
    3             naren9      CCV          Java, Unix
```

Comment: Can you include example data from `projects`?

Comment: I'd like to see the result rows; the two, and the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One explanation would be if the value in `expertise_desc` contained a trailing space, ie `'Java '` (not `'Java'`). Then the  concat value would be `'%java %'`, not `'%java%'`, making a difference.

If one of your project names *ended* with `java`, and the other had `java` *within* the name, only one would match using the join, but two would match with the non-join.

Comment: I see, ok, how do i trim the spaces within the 2nd table ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
SELECT 
      a.project_code as projectCode, 
      a.project_name as projectName, 
      a.project_creation_date as projectCreationDate, 
      a.project_end_date as projectEndDate, 
      a.project_status as projectStatus      
from projects a, tmp_rec_naren8 b
where a.project_name like concat("%",b.expertise_desc,"%") 
    OR a.project_description like concat("%",b.expertise_desc,"%") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
SELECT        
a.project_code as projectCode,        
a.project_name as projectName,        
a.project_creation_date as projectCreationDate,        
a.project_end_date as projectEndDate,        
a.project_status as projectStatus       
from projects,tmp_rec_naren8
where LOCATE(TRIM(tmp_rec_naren8.expertise_desc),projects.project_name) > 0
or
LOCATE(TRIM(tmp_rec_naren8.expertise_desc),projects.project_description) > 0
```

Comment: @NarenGokal, see edit. You can use `trim()` function while comparing `expertise_desc`.